# Does free trial achievable via introductory price in IAP ?(IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

Summing up my R&D free trial via introductory price only meant to be free for specific time after customer bought subscription.
I want that feature to be initially free for a month and then user buy the subscription.

How can I achieve this ?Is it achievable via Introductory price?

Answer (score 1):

- Yes It is achievable by introductory price. You can choose free trial
  duration for a month inside introductory price's.
- With Free trial, New subscribers access content for free for a
  specified duration(say month). Their subscription begins immediately but theywon’t be billed until the free trial period is over.

Check it out for more details : [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase/offering_introductory_prices_in_your_app)

Comment: Hi Shivam , thanks for the answer. For introductory price user is mandatory to buy subscription then only user is able to enjoy trial period. Then after automatically payment will be deducted , right ? I don't want this , I want user to enjoy 1st month freely then after app ask for subscription.

Comment: User can cancel subscription anytime during free trial period,I think  what u are expecting is not feasible with IAP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking that, if user can get free month trial subscription without going for IAP subscription purchase. You need to set logic for that by your own, that after user has installed your app, he/she should be able to use services for a month and after a month all those services should get blocked. and it will be again enabled only after user purchase subscription.